# Javascript/JQuery Datagrid to Show/Edit/Enter in data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datagrid

Javascript/JQuery Datagrid to Show/Edit/Enter data in tables

I want views on the best data grid to use with JS/JQuery

I want to use it with JSON and with arrays also...

The more light the grid the better (less size)

The more compact the better (ideally only 1 *.js file to import)

Should show data in lines/cols system and have facilities to work with rows and colums
(get/set data in row/col/cell, hide/show row/column, hi-lite row/column/cell/range, selece row/coll/cell/range, return array os data in row/col/cell/range, etc.)
If you know more facilities the grid should have (are more or less standard in data grids)
please comment...

Free to use or better... Open source!
I was following the progress in JQueryGrid but is taking to long to be available...

THX, ZEE

Comment: I guess this guy is as pis***of as I am about the datagrid          and the other "not so good stuff" in js/html/css...             thank God there are JQuery/JSON and a few other stuff...          but there must be more...
--- **bold**
Zed A. Shaw - The Web Will Die When OOP Dies                      >> [link](http://vimeo.com/43380467)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% getting what you want but maybe take a look a this open source JavaScript library: [EditableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/) it has most of the things you asked...I guess